# How do I evaluate and explain the running time for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time, evaluation

Pseudo code :

```
    s <- 0
    for i=1 to n do
        if A[i]=1 then 
            for j=1 to n do
                {constant number of elementary operations}
            endfor
        else
            s <- s + a[i]
        endif
    endfor
```

where A[i] is an array of n integers, each of which is a random value between 1 and 6.

I'm at loss here...picking from my notes and some other sources online, I get

T(n) = C1(N) + C2 + C3(N) + C4(N) + C5

where C1(N) and C3(N) = for loops, and C4(N) = constant number of elementary operations. Though I have a strong feeling that I'm wrong.

Comment: what is A[i]? You never initialise it.

Comment: What's the complexity of `A[i]`, too?

Comment: Well the question only shows that A is an array of n integers each of which is a random value between 1 to 6...

Comment: You are looping from 1..n, and each loop ALSO loops from 1..n (in the worst case). O(n^2) right?

Comment: `Running time` is what you use benchmarks for. What you're talking about is [time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)

Answer (score 0):

You are looping from 1..n, and each loop ALSO loops from 1..n (in the worst case). O(n^2) right?

Put another way: You shouldn't be *adding* C3(N). That would be the case if you had two independent for loops from 1..n. But you have a *nested* loop. You will run the inner loop N times, and the outer loop N times. N*N = O(n^2).

Comment: So basically all I have to write is T(n) = O(N^2) ? or should I add the third C3(N) ?

Comment: When people talk about time complexity they are expecting something like O(n^2) or O(nlgn). Even in the case where you *did* have two loops from 1..n (not nested), you would still write O(n) *not* O(n) + O(n). Heck, you might have 50,000 loops that go from 1..n; still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Let's think for a second about what this algorithm does.

You are basically looping through every element in the array at least once (outer for, the one with i). Sometimes, if the value A[i] is 1, you are also looping again through the whole loop with the j for.

In your worst case scenario, you are running against an array of all 1's.

In that case, your complexity is:

- time to init s
- n * (time to test a[i] == 1 + n * time of {constant ...})

Which means: T = T(s) + n * (T(test) + n * T(const)) = n^2 * T(const) + n*T(test) + T(s).
Asymptotically, this is a O(n^2).

But this was a worst-case analysis (the one you should perform most of the times). What if we want an average case analysis?

In that case, assuming an uniform distribution of values in A, you are going to access the for loop of j, on average, 1/6 of the times.

So you'd get:
- time to init s
- n * (time to test a[i] == 1 + 1/6 * n * time of {constant ...} + 5/6 * T(increment s)

Which means: T = T(s) + n * (T(test) + 1/6 * n * T(const) + 5/6 * T(inc s)) = 1/6* n^2 * T(const) + n * (5/6 * T(inc s) + T(test)) + T(s).

Again, asymptotically this is still O(n^2), but according to the value of T(inc s) this could be larger or lower than the other case.

Fun exercise: can you estimate the expected average run time for a generic distribution of values in A, instead of an uniform one?